# How can I add a Loop Function and 1-minute delay to my Python script?

Tags: python, sleep

I have a Python script that reads individual stock ID names from a data file and then calls a URL for each unique ID and writes an output file. I would like to change this code to only execute 5 ID's, then wait 60 seconds, execute 5 more, wait another 60 seconds, etc., until the list is complete.  I was thinking to use the Sleep(60) function and create some type of Loop, but wasn't sure of the best way to do this in Python. Can anyone help modify my code below to accomplish this?  Thanks.

```
# Import the library
import urllib.request

url_base = "https://www.website.com/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol={}&outputsize=full&apikey=123&datatype=csv"

dest_path = "C:/Users/ScriptTest/Date/{}.csv"

symbols = open("symbols.txt").read().strip().split("\n")

for symbol in symbols:
  url = url_base.format(symbol) # Add the curret symbol to base URL
  dest = dest_path.format(symbol) # Add the curret symbol as the file name
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, dest) # Save the current file
```

**Would like to execute the last 3 lines above 5x, then pause 60 seconds, then execute the next 5 symbols, etc. until the list is exhausted.

Comment: Sorry, this is Python code I think.  Wrote this awhile ago.

Comment: So what's your question? Please fix what you posted.

Comment: Same question, how do I write a loop function to execute the last 3 lines 5x, then sleep for 60 seconds, then execute 5 more, then sleep, etc.  Not sure how to create a nested loop using the FOR function in Python...

Comment: You're looking for `time.sleep` function?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the above would work,

```
from time import sleep

n = 1
for symbol in symbols:
  url = url_base.format(symbol) # Add the curret symbol to base URL
  dest = dest_path.format(symbol) # Add the curret symbol as the file name
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, dest) # Save the current file
  if n % 5 == 0:
    sleep(60)
  n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
#add import time
c=0
for symbol in symbols:

  if c==5:
     time.sleep(60)
     c=0
  url = url_base.format(symbol) # Add the curret symbol to base URL
  dest = dest_path.format(symbol) # Add the curret symbol as the file name
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, dest)
  c+=1
```